# How i can get selected parts from string?

Tags: vb.net

How i get string like

> 'EJ0004','EK0001','EA0001'

from string like

> {Emaster.Emp_Code}='EJ0004' OR {Emaster.Emp_Code}='EK0001' OR {Emaster.Emp_Code}='EA0001'

in VB.NET?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

---

**Example:**

```
Sub Main
    Dim s = "{Emaster.Emp_Code}='EJ0004' OR {Emaster.Emp_Code}='EK0001' OR {Emaster.Emp_Code}='EA0001'"
    Dim pattern = "('\w*')"
    Dim matches = Regex.Matches(s, pattern)
    Dim values  = matches.OfType(Of Match).Select(Function(m) m.Value)

    For Each v in values
        Console.WriteLine(v)
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", values))
End Sub
```

**Output:**

> 'EJ0004'
>   'EK0001'
>   'EA0001'
>   'EJ0004','EK0001','EA0001'

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways you could do this, here i offer one simple way:

```
dim yourString as string = 'This is the variable which holds your initial string
dim newString as string = yourString.replace("{Emaster.Emp_Code}=", "").replace(" OR ",",")
```

Now newString will hold 'EA0001' Or whatever.
If you want it without the '' then do

```
dim newString as string = yourString.replace("{Emaster.Emp_Code}=", "").replace("'","").replace(" OR ",",")
```